# JS не видит переменную, переданную через res.send

Tags: javascript, node.js

На сервере передаю переменную

```
res.render('user',{newsAll:data});
```

Клиент принимает эти данные и даже выводит в html (использую pug)

```
p #{newsAll[i]['category']}
```

Всё выводит отлично, но когда я пытаюсь получить доступ к переменной через js, то он её не видит

```
newsAll.forEach(function(element) {

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

метод `render` передает объект как параметр шаблонизатора, поэтому внутри шаблонизатора можно обращаться напрямую к свойствам этого объекта.

В свою очередь на клиенте про переменную так ничего и не известно, так как она нигде не объявляется.

Comment: Спасибо, что объяснили, подскажите пожалуйста как изменить код, чтобы переменная была доступна

Comment: @ВикторияШевченко, в принципе никак, клиентский код выполняется на клиенте, серверный на сервере, в общем случае они никак не связаны. Можно попробовать в шаблоне вывести тег script, в котором сделать `var newsAll = ...` где вместо `...` провести рендер нужных полей. Либо на клиенте делать запрос на сервер, получать от него json, парсить его и присваивать результат нужно переменной на клиенте.